# How to disable git for some project and other project not disable git in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio, editor, visual-studio-code

some project i don't want use git monitoring , but in other project i want to keep use git monitoring , i use setting

```
"git.enabled": false,
"git.path": null,
"git.autofetch": false
```

but it will disable git for all project , so how to setting Visual Studio Code git for project instead of the editor?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You could add your git settings to the workspace settings.json file. That way, vscode would ignore git changes for only that project. Create or add to the .vscode/settings.json file.

```
"git.enabled": false
```

This way all of your other project will continue have git enabled.

Comment: I think the correct format is:
{
"git.enabled": false
}

Answer (score 21):

To follow up with @alexriedl's answer, that snippet would be added into `settings.json` to apply for that workspace only:

```
{
    "git.enabled": false
}
```

Here's an example folder structure:

```
myproject/
├── .vscode/
│   ├── settings.json <----
├── html/
│   ├── index.html
│   └── 404.html
└── js/
    ├── bootstrap.js
    └── bootstrap.min.js
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution by simply using the VSCode UI:

- right click on project name
- click on "Open Folder Settings"
- open "Extensions" then "Git"
- scroll down until "Enabled - Whether git is enabled"
- uncheck it

Answer (score 0):

---

### **first way :**

1. Open the command palette (either with `F1` or `Ctrl+Shift+P`)
2. Type "open settings"
3. choose `Open Settings (JSON)`
4. add     **`"git.enabled": false`** to the settings.json file

### second way  :

1. create `.gitignore` file in your project (maybe you already have it )
2. add

> 

```
* 
*/
```

- to ignore all files in your project

Answer (score 0):

The answer is similar to the best (up to now, 2022-09-06) answer of [alexriedl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43286241/3734141). You can add all of these projects to a new [workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/workspaces), and in the file defining the workspace you can disable the Git extension at all or in a more specific way:

```
{
    "folders": [
        {
            "path": "."
        }
    ],
    "settings": {
        "git.enabled": false
    }
}
```

How to create a new workspace? Open the folder with any of the projects, then go to the menu **File > Save Workspace As...**. And to the selected file with the .code-workspace extension you have to put a similar code like above.

Note: If you are using the Bitbucket extension also (like me), you can be notified about some failures. Go to the Extensions tab, find the Bitbucket extension, and disable it for the same workspace - look carefully, the button **Diasable** is a drop-down button, **Disable (Workspace)** is below the main.

Answer (score -1):

You could add * in your **.gitignore** file

```
#to ignore all project's file
*
```

Comment: And effectively disable git in that project completely, not just in VSC? Excellent idea.

Answer (score -4):

You can remove .git folder in the project's root directory to disable git, by using:

`rm -rf .git`

Comment: OP asked how to disable, not how to remove git support.

Comment: Oh man , this was violent